# Divide template for several file doesn't provide data

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I've template with 1 file (original file)**which works as expected**, now when it comes bigger I've started to divide it to `3 files` and just copy and paste the data from the original file to 3 files and I was able to see that the template was executed successfully but the data is missing in the `start` and the `end` template ,just the `main` template receive the data properly from `structData`

for example

```
startTemple.txt

{{define "start"}}
...

{{end}}


main.txt (here i include both template)

{{template "start"}}
...

{{template "end"}}


endTemplate.txt


{{define "end"}}
...
{{end}}
```

**I use the following**

```
t, err := template.New(mainTemplateName).Funcs(funcMap).ParseFiles(startPath, mainPath, endPath)

err = t.Execute(templFile, structData)
if err != nil {
    logs.Logger.Error(err)
}
```

I use the exact code as before and the issue is that the data from `structData` is not appear in `start` and `end` template after generation, just in the `main` is getting the structData properly, what could I be missing here ?

the **templates** (start main end) was generated successfully with the **hardcoded data**, but the data which should come from `structData`, is not add during the generation to the `start` and `end` templates

Should I add the `structData` also to the `start` and `end` somehow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `template` to invoke another template, `dot` is not set by default, but you can pass the value as an (optional) second parameter to `template` like this:

```
{{template "name"  pipeline}}
```

In your case, your `main.txt` template should be

```
{{template "start" .}}
...
{{template "end" .}}
```

to pass the value of `dot` down to the `start` and `end` template.

Because the value of `dot` can be set this way, it is also possible to split templates up into multiple files in more complex ways. For example, you could have an HTML template to display the user information in a card-style fashion, and wherever you want to insert this card in your output, you can just invoke the template and pass it the user, even when the surrounding template needs other information as well or in a loop.

For more details, check the [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions) docs. This works both for `text/template` and `html/template`, but is only documented explicitly for `text/template`, while there is a note at the start of documentation for `html/template` telling you, where the detailed documentation can be found.

Comment: Can you please provide the link where it's explained on the missing `.` I didnt find it in links , but your example solved my issue. thank you very much !!!

Comment: In the linked section (Actions) of the [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions) documentation, they state: `{{template "name" pipeline}}` - The template with the specified name is executed with dot set to the value of the pipeline. Right above that it says: `{{template "name"}}` - The template with the specified name is executed with nil data.